# Deploying the JavaEE 8 Tutorial, by maven gets Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.4:redeploy (deploy) on project hello1

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I attempted to deploy hello1 project (an example of [Java EE SDK v8 tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html)) on glassfish v5 by maven command:

```
$ mvn install
```

it gets these errors:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.658 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-12-03T11:33:57+03:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/291M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.4:redeploy (deploy) on project hello1: Execution deploy of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.4:redeploy failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [glassfish5x], type = [installed]], configuration type [existing]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

I will appreciate, if someone answers, how this problem should be solved.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. that error occurred because glassfish server has not started already.
I had to start glassfish server, before deploying (using command $ mvn install)
note that glassfish v4 needs JDK6 or JDK7. and glassfish v5 needs JDK7 or JDK8.